# Calendar not aligned in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to print out a calendar in tkinter but it doesn't print aligned. If I print it in the python console it prints fine. I read on stack overflow to use `justify = Left` but that still hasn't fixed it.

```
from tkinter import *
import calendar

tk = Tk()

calendar_ = calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.MONDAY).formatyear(2017)
calendar_gui = Label(tk, text = calendar_, bg = "white", justify = LEFT)
calendar_gui.pack()

print(calendar_)

tk.geometry("1280x720")
tk.title("Calendar")
tk.configure(background = "white")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the font of the `calendar_gui` to `Courier New`, like this:

```
calendar_gui = tk.Label(window, text=calendar_, bg="white", font=("Courier New", 10, "bold))
```

This may not always work, however if you don't have `Courier New` in the font files.

Also, don't use wildcard imports (`from ... import *`) and don't name your window `tk`. It can mess things up.

Comment: You left out the closing quotation mark on `"bold"`. You also need the `, justify = LEFT` as well.

Comment: Also, how will `tk` mess things up? I checked and there doesn't seem to be anything called `tk` in tkinter.